# In what folder does outlook express 6 store mail on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, outlook-express, email

In what folder does outlook express 6 store mail on windows XP?
I don't need to migrate or export, I just need to know the folder (or registry) location where the mail is stored by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\<GUID>\Microsoft\Outlook Express\*.dbx
```

Comment: @Yuri: [Here's another.](http://getthunderbird.com)

Comment: It's not for me, I don't use outlook express, I just finished doing a hard drive swap for someone else, so copy pasting the folder was a must, this + registry + address book and everything works. :D

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook, go to Tools> Options> Maintenance Tab >Store Folder button, highlight and copy the path, then open a run command and paste it in there, hit OK.

If OE will not open browse there manually using Windows Explorer

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Identities\\Microsoft\Outlook Express\

The string of numbers and letters folder will be a unique identifier for Each Identity in OE if they set up more than one Identity there will be more than one of these guid folders, one for each Identity.

Comment: what if I can't open outlook for it's crashy reasons?

Comment: Check my edit above.

Comment: but if the whole user profile thing crashed in the end not even internet explorer will work...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably in an OE6 or OES folder. This folder could be located in a directory similar to the way they have it setup in Windows 7 which is: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OES or OE6\

-Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just issue the following command and you should be fine :)

```
dir "\*.dbx" /s
```

This would display whatever folder has a .dbx(file created by outlook) file in it